# NeDB regex operator called with non regular expression

Tags: nedb

I'm trying to search string using regex as below:

```
db.find({ consignee: { $regex: /test/ } }, function (err, docs) {

});
```

But it is throwing error

**Error: $regex operator called with non regular expression**

Comment: what version of NeDB are you using? Make sure you have the latest by running `npm install nedb` and make sure it is `1.8.0`, if it still doesn't work then add your node and npm version to the question

Comment: I am using the same version 1.8.0

Comment: What happens when you do `db.find({}, function (err, docs) {

});`. I have tried most combinations and almost in every case it works https://jsfiddle.net/tarunlalwani/7qf1kL00/2/

Comment: It returns all the docs but I need only docs which contain consignee having sub string "test"

Comment: Possible to share a minimal reproducible git ? I am not able to reproduce as of now, whatever I do

Comment: I am using it with electron and saving it into the file.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/170127/discussion-between-tarun-lalwani-and-rohit).

Comment: @TarunLalwani It's working now. Now I am generating regex on backend using Node.js. It seems to be an issue with Angular. Thanks Tarun for the help!

Comment: Do you want me to post that as an answer? Also  in angular did you try with `new RegExp("/ar/")`?

Comment: It's not working from front end. It's working fine with node.js

Comment: That's why you need to provide a reproducible git repo